# How to organize backbone.js app with jQuery autocomplete plugin?

Tags: javascript, architecture, backbone.js

I'm pretty new to Backbone.JS and can't understand how many views, collections, models should I create for my application.

My application consists of two parts. At the left side I have an input tag, which should support autocomplete. Autocomplete dropdown displays results as buttons. When user clicks any button, I need to update DB and add that button into separate view in dom, which contains saved entities. I made a small wireframe.

[image: Wireframe of an application]

I don't need the code, just help me with general architecture. Should I create separate view for left side, for each button and for right side ? What about collections ? How many of those ? I read a lot of backbone.js documentation, but when started to do on my own - a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

Your mock up can be interpreted in different ways (that's the beauty of backbone...).

One way will probably be a main view that will hold and handle events for the other 2 sub views:

1. autocomplete view
2. selected button view

Main view will handle db connection for first view and call render on it upon success save operation
as well as delete buttons up on a delete trigger from the second view, and then render second view.

Of course it can be implemented in various other ways:

[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJwgIth1I_w) simple video can get you started.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663428/how-to-correctly-add-a-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-using-backbone-js/9663694#9663694) post can help.

Look at the answer by @miguelr.